# Oracle several clobs insert in php

Tags: php, sql, oracle, clob

The problem is, that I had a table with 1 clob column, and to insert new row I used this:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, NAME, DATA)
    VALUES (:ID, :NAME, EMPTY_CLOB())
    RETURNING DATA INTO :DATA
```

Now, I have added one more clob field - NEW_DATA, and I still want to insert the new data in this field.

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, NAME, DATA, NEW_DATA)
    VALUES (:ID, :NAME, EMPTY_CLOB(),EMPTY_CLOB())
    RETURNING DATA, NEW_DATA INTO :DATA,:NEW_DATA
```

Can you help me with this issue? How to insert more than 1 clob through the insert command?

Comment: What's the error you are seeing?  Why does your PHP code look like?  When in doubt, check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Comment: The problem is solved and it was about PHP, thanks for help. The last example is right.